# How to grant android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permissions to android shell user?

Tags: android, permissions, android-ndk, audiorecord

I build some command line tool with android NDK and execute it in /data/local/tmp. Now it prompts me “requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO”. It's usually in AndroidManifest.xml for java application, but how to grant it to android shell user?

Source code like:

```
sp<AudioRecord> rec = new AudioRecord(AUDIO_SOURCE_MIC, 44100, AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_16_BIT, AUDIO_CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
```

Logcat:

```
I/AudioFlinger( 3772): AudioFlinger's thread 0xf0e838c0 ready to run
W/ServiceManager( 3772): Permission failure:android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=2000 pid=-1
E/        ( 3772): Request requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
E/AudioFlinger( 3772): openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
E/AudioRecord(14132): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
--------- beginning of crash
...
```

Answer (score 8):

After Lollipop, Android platform is using real time permissions. If your app running in Marshmallow and after versions, you should grant your permissions in Activity.

Before request permissions:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // put your code for Version>=Marshmallow
        } else {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "App required access to audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
        }

    } else {
        // put your code for Version < Marshmallow
    }
```

After this, overraide this method and put your code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

  if (requestCode == REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Application will not have audio on record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what your target SDK is, if your target SDK is 23 and below, you don't have to give runtime permissions.

Answer (score 4):

```
  private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {

        String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

        // If the user previously denied this permission then show a message explaining why
        // this permission is needed
        if (getActivity().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This app needs to record audio through the microphone....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{requiredPermission}, 101);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 101 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // This method is called when the  permissions are given
        }

    }
```

Execute this code if you have device with marshmallow or upper OS